# Do NaHCO3 and cyanoacrylate react?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, polymers, safety

I just saw [this video](https://youtu.be/ImLAmfM_AgA) about using baking soda + cyanoacrylate(CA) glue as a substrate+resin.

- Neat, but do CA and $\ce{NaHCO3}$ react in any way?
- If so, what does the equation look like and what is the resulting structure?
- If not at room temperature, do they react at higher temperatures because CA curing is exothermic.
- Is the CA + $\ce{NaHCO3}$ stable once it dries, is there any residue that would be toxic or irritating?

(not sure what to tag this with, feel free to add tags)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Baking soda"(*) speeds up the cyanoacrylate curing, as it's basic anion initiates anionic polymeration. Similarly as benzoyl peroxide initiates radical polymeration of styrene to polystyrene.

$$\ce{HO-CO-O- ->[CH2=CR1R2] \\
HO-CO-O-CH2-CR1R2- ->[CH2=CR1R2] \\
HO-CO-O-CH2-CR1R2-CH2-CR1R2- ... etc}$$

While curing, there is expected stronger evaporation of monomeric cyanoacrylate, compared to standard curing, due faster reaction, which may be irritating. When cured, the safety concerns are the same as for ordinary cyanoacrylate curing and usage, which has medicinal applications too.

Note that advices about medical safety, acute and especially long term one, is explicitly off-topic on this site, which would comment just chemical aspects of safe manipulation and precautions.

The higher temperature is issue for the structural stability, as the remaining encapsulated baking soda may decompose, forming gaseous carbon dioxide.

---

(*) -  "Baking soda" = sodium bicarbonate, $\ce{NaHCO3}$. Not to be confused with sodium carbonate, $\ce{Na2CO3}$ resp. $\ce{Na2CO3 . 10 H2O}$ aka 'washing soda", which is caustic, while baking soda is not.